# I keep getting an AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__get_author'. Could someone please help me with what I can do to fix it?

Tags: python

I am creating a tweet manager and i'm coming upon a attribute error that i honestly don't know how to fix. I am a novice at Python so I'm still learning. Why am I getting AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__get_author'. Here is my code:

```
# The running flag and the tweets list are initialized here
running = True
tweets = []


# This will function as our main loop
while(running):

    # Get the user's input using the input command to display the menu
    print('Tweet Menu ----------------\n' \
                    '1. Make a Tweet\n' \
                    '2. View Recent Tweets\n' \
                    '3. Search Tweets\n' \
                    '4. Quit\n')
    choice = input('What would you like to do?')

    # Make sure the input is an integer
    try:
        value = int(choice)
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a numeric value")
        continue

    # Handle "Make a Tweet" input
    if value == 1:
        name = str(input('What is your name?'))
        tweeting = True
        while (tweeting):
            message = str(input('What would you like to tweet?'))
            if len(message) < 140:
                tweet = (name, message)
                tweets.append(tweet)
                print(name + ", your tweet has been saved.")
                tweeting = False
            else:
                print("Tweets can only be 140 characters!")

    # Handle "View Recent Tweets" input
    elif value == 2:
        if len(tweets) == 0:
            print("There are no tweets saved")
        else:
            for i in range(len(tweets)-1, len(tweets) -6, -1):
                print(tweet[i].__get_author())
                print(tweet[i].__get_text())
                print(tweet[i].__get_age())

    # Handle "Search Tweets" input
    elif value == 3:
        if len(tweets) == 0:
            print("There are no tweets saved")
        else:
            found = False # A flag to see if we found a matching tweet
            search_key = str(input('What would you like to search for?'))
            for i in range(len(tweets)-1, 0, -1):
                if search_key in tweets[i].__get_text():
                    print(tweets[i].__get_author())
                    print(tweets[i].__get_text())
                    print(tweets[i].__get_age())
                    found = True
            if found == False:
                print("No tweets contained " + search_key)

    # Handle "Quit" input
    # This is where you'll want to save the tweets to a .dat file
    elif value == 4:
        if len(tweets) > 0:

            # SAVE THE TWEETS TO A .DAT FILE HERE
            import pickle

            tweets = message

            output_file = open('tweets.dat', 'wb')
            pickle.dump(tweets, output_file)
            output_file.close()




        print("Thank you for using the Tweet Manager!")
        running = False

    # Handle inputs that are not in range 1 to 4 inclusive
    else:
        print("Please select a valid option")
```

The other program i have is Twitter.py which goes hand in hand with this program.
Here is Twitter.py's code:

import time

class Tweet:
    'Class for a tweet'

```
# init function creates a Tweet
def __init__(self, author, text):
    self.author = author
    self.text = text
    self.age = time.time()

# returns author of tweet
def __get_author(self):
    return self.author

# returns text of tweet
def __get_text(self):
    return self.text

# returns age of tweet in the correct format
def __get_age(self):
    elapsed = time.time() - self.age
    if elapsed < 60:
        return str(int(elapsed)) + 's'
    elif elapsed/60 < 60:
        return str(int(elapsed/60)) + 'm'
    else:
        return str(int(elapsed/3600)) + 'h'
```

Comment: It's unclear from your code what `tweets` is supposed to be. You initialize it as a list with `[]`, then in case 1 you append a tuple to it. In case 2 you seem to expect it to contain objects with `__get_author()` etc methods. Which it doesn't, if it contains tuples. And finally in case 4 you assign a string to `tweets`, which throws away anything you might have put in there and makes it a string (whatever `message` happens to be). It looks like you have some work to do to clean up your code.

Comment: what is this `__get_author()` and why should it magically work without mentions in the code.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I added the second piece to the code

Comment: Why do you use a double underscore at the start of your method names if you want to use those methods from outside?

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanted to call `tweets[i]` instead of `tweet[i]` within 'Handle "View Recent Tweets" input'

Comment: when I did that, instead of 'str' in the error, it said 'tuple' object has no attribute __get_author.

Comment: Another thing. You create a tuple 'tweet = (name, message)' which looks like you actually want to call the C'tor of the Tweet class = > meaning 'Tweet(name, message)'

Comment: I'm slightly confused, what should I do to fix this problem then if I might ask?

Comment: In ' # Handle "Make a Tweet" input' block you have a line 'tweet = (name, message)'. Change it to  'tweet = Tweet(name, message)' in order to create a Tweet object.

Comment: I tried that and I got a NameError saying 'Tweet' is not defined.

Comment: Is it on the same module? Have you imported it if not?

Comment: When i try to import 'Tweet', I get ImportError: No module named 'Tweet'.

Comment: @Kman: How did you get the idea that there is a module named `Tweet`? According to your question you have a class `Tweet` in the module `Twitter`. You have to do `from Twitter import Tweet`. After you've done this all the other errors in your code will show up ...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing a call to your object constructor. Instead of:

```
            tweet = (name, message)
```

do

```
            tweet = Tweet(name, message)
```

My comments (in the comments section above) about case 4 still hold. It's unclear why the line `tweets = message` exists.

Comment: I used the Tweets =  message because I am supposed to display the tweet that the author had created  in a .dat file.